# Can the closed interval [0, 1] be expressed as the union of a sequence of disjoint closed subintervals each of length smaller than 1?

Tags: analysis

Can the closed interval [0, 1] be expressed as the union of a sequence of disjoint closed
subintervals each of length smaller than 1? Explain.

I have been trying to figure out this problem, and I do not know where to even begin.

Comment: @PeterFranek They are *closed* intervals, not open ones, so compactness doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Supposing $I_n$ were such a sequence of closed intervals, consider the union of their boundary points $B=\bigcup\partial I_n$. Can you show that $B$, as a subspace of $[0, 1]$, is a complete metric space? What can you say about each set $\partial I_n$ as a subset of $B$ (HINT: think about density)? Do you know a theorem about how the countable union of such sets must behave in a complete metric space?

Comment: Nice. Much better than the grubby proof I'd have given. Let's see.. $B$ is a closed set (therefore complete though I don't see how that helps). $\partial I_n$ is finite, so $B$ is countable (don't know what "as a subset of $B$" means here). Plainly, $B$ has no isolated points. So $B$ is a countable perfect set. The theorem we need is that every nonempty perfect subset of $\mathbb R$ has the cardinality of the continuum. Am I right?

Comment: @bof That's one way to do it, although that doesn't extend to closed *sets*. I was thinking of something more Baire-bones.